# Move subset of data between SQL databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two customers databases, both has the same structure.  I need to move some of customers(customerID) and their related info from one database to our test database, since there are multiple tables involved(with constrain), How should I accomplish it? Do I need to first drop all the constrain in the tables on target database?  Is there a guideline or some sample script on this job?

Answer (score 1):

If you do this in the right order, there is no need to drop the contraints. Do the "leaf" tables first, which are the ones with no dependencies, and work your way through all the tables in this matter.

You can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Destinationdb.owner.table
Select * From SourceDB.owner.table
```

If you have identity fields in any of the tables, before the insert run

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE ON
```

and after the INSERT run

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE OFF
```

Edit:
One thing I forgot. If you have constraints, then you can't TRUNCATE a table, so if you leave the constraints, then you'll have to run DELETE statements to clear out the destination tables first. If you have a lot of data, this could become impractcal, in which case you will want to script out the contraints, drop them, truncate the data (rather than delete since it saves on transactions), copy the data, then run the script to re-enable all of the constraints.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I was thinking to start with the parent table instead of leaf table.  DO I need to link these two database servers before run INSERT INTO statement? Also, it should not TRUNCATE a dest. table, since I just insert more rows into the existing table?

Comment: @Bekka28 if separate servers, then yes they need to be linked. If not, no need to link, just do a cross database query. In regards to truncate, if you want a clean copy of the prod data, then you need to, otherwise it doesn't matter unless other constraints will be violated.